# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()... Error

Tags: php, html5, array, foreach, error404

tengo el siguiente problema en mi web, cuando verifico el archivo "error_log" este em muestra el siguiente error:

*"Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ ..."*

Esta en la ubicación del error:

```
<?php                                       

        foreach ($on['result'] as $val) { ?>

            <a href="#" onClick="goToProfile(<?= $val['id'];?>)"><li class="chat__human" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">

                <img class="chat__avatar" style="padding: 1px;margin:3px" src="<?= $val['photo'];?>" alt="" />

                <span class="chat__name comforta" style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 5px;font-weight: bold"><?= $val['firstName'];?></span>

                <span class="chat__last_m" style="position: absolute;margin-left:5px;margin-top: 23px;color:#999"> <?= $val['last_m'];?></span>

            </li></a>             

        <?php } ?>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a solucionar este error, gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `$on['result']`? Puedes hacerle un `var_dump` antes

Comment: <?php $query = 'id='.$sm['user']['id']; $action = 'getOnlineFriends'; $on = apiCall($action,$query); ?>

Comment: Te regresa algo `apiCall($action,$query)`?  haz un `var_dump` en `$on` esto para ir depurando los errores.